# Hadoop Cluster. Map reduce job stuck at map 100% and reduce 0%

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. I tried to create a hadoop cluster based on the example given on the Apache [Hadoop site](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html%60%60).

However when I run the map reduce example the application is stuck at map 100% and reduce 0%.

Please help

I have setup the environment using Vagrant and Virtual box. Created two instances.

I am running name node and a data node in one instance and resource manager and node manager in the other instance.

mapred-siet.xml configuration

```
<configuration>

<!-- Map Reduce applications configuration -->
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>1536</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx1024M</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>3072</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx2560M</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor</name>
    <value>100</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies</name>
    <value>50</value>
</property>


<!-- Map Reduce Job History Server -->
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name>
    <value>/mr-history/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name>
    <value>/mr-history/done</value>
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
e<configuration>
<!-- Resource Manager -->
<property>
    <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>1024</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
</property>

<!-- Node Manager -->
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
</property>  
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
    <value>2.1</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
    <value>/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/tempData</value>
</property>  
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
    <value>/opt/hadoop-2.6.2/logDir</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds</name>
    <value>10800</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
    <value>/logs</value>
</property> 
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property> 

<!-- History Server -->
<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
    <value>-1</value>
</property>   
<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-check-interval-seconds</name>
    <value>-1</value>
</property>
```

Comment: What have you set the # of mappers and # of reducers too?  Do you have 0 reducers by chance?

Comment: Also can you post your mapreduce code?  If you don't use a reducer for example this will happen

Comment: We can' t help you unless you post the code

Comment: Thank you for looking into this issue. 
I have used the sample example provided in apache site..
bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'

This was working for me when I tried to run it as a psuedo cluster.


Also I don't know the configuration file where I have to set the mapper and reducer.

Comment: Look out for top left corner in this link. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html - core-default, hdfs-default, mapred-default and yarn-default xmls

Comment: Thanks Ravindra. 
I think the issue is with the memory I am using for my Virtual machine. I think it is not enough and because of this reducers cannot be started. Could you give me some recommended memory amount I should use. Since I am using Vagrant, I can configure the amount of RAM required in the Vagrant File.

Comment: i have added my mapred-site.xml configuration file and yarn-site.xml. Could you check and let me know, if I have made some errors in configuring the memory required. Also if this is the memory required, what should be the RAM required for each system. I am running data node and name node in one instance. The other instance is running resourcemanager and nodemanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run the application now. As I thought it was a problem with the memory required by the system. I changed the following properties as given below
    
        yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb
        8192

```
<!-- Node Manager -->
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>8192</value>
</property>
```

and repeated the process. its working fine now.